# mysql: getting affected rows of an insert to a temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

after I perform an insert to a temporary table i would like to get the number of affected rows (how many rows i insert to the table).

what's the equivalent command of `mysql_affected_rows()` in SQL?

`ROW_COUNT()` returns **-1**;

using Mysql Server 5.1

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytest select login_token.id from login_token;
```

when I use the following command, MySQL returns the following status:

```
Query OK, 301 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 301  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

but when I query for ROW_COUNT():

```
mysql> select ROW_COUNT();
+-------------+
| ROW_COUNT() |
+-------------+
|          -1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I searched the net a lot and i found that the only proper solution is to run a count query.

```
select count(1) from  mytest;
```

Answer (score 2):

[ROW COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) might be what you are looking for. Read the docs, there are details.

EDIT:
As I said, there are details - ROW_COUNT() works only from the same session and only immediately following an update query, otherwise it resets to -1.
There are other details, read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean from sql query ?

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```